# whatsapp business api giving error wacore not instantiated

Tags: docker-compose, whatsapp

Currently i am working on whatsapp business api setup using docker . 
I have followed the instructions specified in installation document.

Installation done successfully and all containers are running fine.
When i am performing the health check getting the  below response

```
{
    "health": {
        "192.168.99.124:337e5a74fec8": {
            "gateway_status": "unregistered",
            "role": "primary_master"
        },
        "192.168.99.125:f6d56ce7a303": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "code": 1011,
                    "title": "Service not ready",
                    "details": "Wacore is not instantiated. Please check wacore log for details."
                }
            ]
        },
        "192.168.99.125:f18358cd1dff": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "code": 1011,
                    "title": "Service not ready",
                    "details": "Wacore is not instantiated. Please check wacore log for details."
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "meta": {
        "version": "v2.25.5",
        "api_status": "stable"
    }
}
```

Two of the core containers (master and wacore) not getting instantiated. 
i verified my containers, all are running .

Does any one faced this issue ? or this one is the normal  because response always  giving 200 status code .

Comment: What did you see !?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the your WhatsApp Business API client for it to work.
Refer the documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/installation/prod-multiconnect